# copy/pasting or copying/pasting?

Tags: word-choice

Should we write:

> I am **copy/pasting** the text

Or:

> I am **copying/pasting** the text

?

Comment: *copy-paste* (third-person singular simple present *copy-pastes*, present participle *copy-pasting*, simple past and past participle *copy-pasted*): https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copy-paste

Comment: Worth noting (and gaining traction, I think) is the slang term [_copypasta_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copypasta#English).

Comment: @J.R. Maybe, but I think *copypasta* more commonly (at least on the internet) describes [something else](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/copypasta) entirely. I'd avoid it unless I meant the specific meaning described there. The Wiktionary definition doesn't quite *do it justice*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern notion of *copy-paste* is new enough in the nomenclature (barely a few decades old, roughly the same age as word processors) that I don't think this matter has been settled yet. Personally, I'd be apt to use hyphens with "and", rather than a slash:

> *I am copying-and-pasting the text*.

That said, I'd have no problem with either of  your versions.

This might also depend on the formality of your document. If you are writing this in an email, it won't really matter. Everyone will know what you mean. However, if you are writing for a journal publication, that might merit more careful deliberation.

Comment: Even though I sometimes use hyphens there myself, it's not a mistake to omit them (and in fact [most people omit them](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copy-and-paste%2Ccopy+and+paste&year_start=1800&year_end=2000)).